# Busybox vs Embutils

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, busybox

I have few queries related to BusyBox & embutils.

Can anyone brief me on the differences between BusyBox and embutils?

It would also be great if you can illustrate scenarios in which these respective tools are being used in embedded Linux environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extract of **Building embedded Linux Systems** book :

embutils was written by the author of diet libc with very similar goals.
Though it supports many of the most common Unix commands, embutils is still far from being as exhaustive as BusyBox. For example, version 0.18 still lacks *find, grep, ifconfig, ps and route*.

In Contrast to BusyBox however, embutils must be statically linked with diet libc. It can't be linked to any other library. Because diet libc is already very small, This can make embutils a better choice than BusyBox when just a few binaries are needed, because the overall size is smaller.

Be aware that the embutils last version is about 6 years old, so not well maintained compared to BusyBox. As usual, choice depends of your needs, goals and contraints.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the embutils is 6 years old and not well maintained compared to busybox.